# Drag & Drop involving accordion panes (VB/ASP)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, drag-and-drop, accordion

I have an accordion control in ASP 3.5, with multiple accordion panes. For the sake of simplicity, I will only focus on one pane as the problem is pane specific. Using JQuery, I created a draggable function and applied it to my .drag CSS class. On Page_Load, I create a bunch of image objects and assign that class to them, in addition to an image. Once I load the page, I can drag all the images around as intended. What I can't do, however, is drag those images outside of the accordion panel they were created in! Is there a way around that? I tried using this, but to no avail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".drag").draggable({ containment: 'document' });
    });
</script>
```

Is there something in the actual aspx page that I should be focusing on? I'm adding the images to a panel in my accordion pane, and it looks like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane id="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
    <Header> Chassis</Header>
    <Content>
        <asp:Panel ID="ChassisPanel" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </Content>
</ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
```

I appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add the clone helper, then anything I drag is able escape its parent container. This is how I updated my drag line and now it works:

```
 $('.drag').draggable({ revert: true,helper: 'clone' });}
```

Now for the life I me I can't figure out the droppable bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this in multiple browsers?  Sounds to me like an issue I had with IE.  Perhaps adding a large Z-Index value to your .drag class in CSS would help.

Comment: I gave it a shot by adding all sorts of zindex values, but no dice. My draggables are still trapped in the accordion pane! take a look at http://www.mobiuspc.com/Configurator.aspx to see what I mean...